# Sql statement just returns boolean

Tags: python, sqlite, combobox

I want to fill my combobox "Box_personal" with personalids from my database, but it only returns "true".

```
def kombobox_fuellen(self):
    result=[]
   abfrage = "SELECT DISTINCT(Personalnummer) as Personalnummer FROM mitarbeiter"
    result = query.exec(abfrage)
    my_list = [r for r, in result]
   self.Box_personal.addItems(my_list)
```

i have also triied, which prints out all the personalnumbers but adds every single digit as own entry to the box

```
def kombobox_fuellen(self):
    # SQL Abfrage aller daten
    result=[]
    abfrage = "SELECT Personalnummer FROM mitarbeiter"
    query.exec(abfrage)
    while query.next():
        result = str(query.value(0))
        print(str(result))
    # self.Box_airline.addItems("")
        self.Box_personal.addItems(result)
```

Comment: if i enter change it to result = str(query.exec(abfrage)) it gets rid of the error and runs, but as thought it just adds "True" as string to the combobox

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little mistake, here's the code and it runs now:

```
def kombobox_fuellen(self):
    # SQL Abfrage aller daten
    abfrage = "SELECT Personalnummer FROM mitarbeiter"
    query.exec(abfrage)
    while query.next():
        result = str(query.value(0))
        print(str(result))
    # self.Box_airline.addItems("")
        self.Box_personal.addItem(result)
```

The problem was the addItems -> changed to addItem and wolla